# MySQL - Group_concat querywithout group

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: design, category and design_category

And I need, a row by each design with diferent category, but with a column with the concat categories. I do the next:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, c.id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id)
FROM design d
LEFT JOIN design_category dc ON dc.design_id = d.id 
LEFT JOIN category c ON dc.category_id = c.id  
GROUP BY d.id


+----+-----------------------------------+------+--------------------+
| id | name                              | id   | GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) |
+----+-----------------------------------+------+--------------------+
|  2 | Design 1                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  4 | Design 2                          |  179 | 179,177,178        |
|  5 | Design 3                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  6 | Design 4                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  7 | Design 5                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  8 | Design 6                          |  181 | 181,180            |
+----+-----------------------------------+------+--------------------+
```

But I wont something like that:

```
+----+-----------------------------------+------+--------------------+
| id | name                              | id   | GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) |
+----+-----------------------------------+------+--------------------+
|  2 | Design 1                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  2 | Design 1                          |  178 | 177,178            |
|  4 | Design 2                          |  177 | 179,177,178        |
|  4 | Design 2                          |  178 | 179,177,178        |
|  4 | Design 2                          |  179 | 179,177,178        |
|  5 | Design 3                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  5 | Design 3                          |  178 | 177,178            |
|  6 | Design 4                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  6 | Design 4                          |  178 | 177,178            |
|  7 | Design 5                          |  177 | 177,178            |
|  7 | Design 5                          |  178 | 177,178            |
|  8 | Design 6                          |  180 | 181,180            |
|  8 | Design 6                          |  181 | 181,180            |
+----+-----------------------------------+------+--------------------+
```

It's possible in MySQL?

Comment: I think change `c.id` to `min(c.id)` in your sql should work. but I did not test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select x.id, x.name, y.id, z.grouped_id from FROM design x
LEFT JOIN design_category xy ON xy.design_id = x.id 
LEFT JOIN category y ON xy.category_id = y.id  
left join(
SELECT d.id id , GROUP_CONCAT(c.id) grouped_id
FROM design d
LEFT JOIN design_category dc ON dc.design_id = d.id 
LEFT JOIN category c ON dc.category_id = c.id  
GROUP BY d.id) zon z.id= x.id
```